# Extracting attachments from SharePoint online using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

Currently I am trying to extract attachments from a list on SharePoint online. I found a code online that is supposed to do this but i get an error. The code that I found is a follows:

```
$webUrl = "https://mm.sharepoint.com/teams/pj-b0000"
$library = "Photos" 
#Local Folder to dump files
$tempLocation = "C:\Users\C\Documents\temp"    
$s = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($webUrl)    
$w = $s.OpenWeb()         
$l = $w.Lists[$library]    
foreach ($listItem in $l.Items)
{
    Write-Host "    Content: " $listItem.ID 
    $destinationfolder = $tempLocation + "\" + $listItem.ID          
    if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationfolder))        
    {            
        $dest = New-Item $destinationfolder -type directory          
    }
    foreach ($attachment in $listItem.Attachments)    
    {        
        $file = $w.GetFile($listItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix + $attachment)        
        $bytes = $file.OpenBinary()                
        $path = $destinationfolder + "\" + $attachment
        Write "Saving $path"
        $fs = new-object System.IO.FileStream($path, "OpenOrCreate") 
        $fs.Write($bytes, 0 , $bytes.Length)    
        $fs.Close()    
    }
}
```

but i get this error:

```
new-object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At C:\Users\C\Documents\SPListExtract.ps1:5 char:6
+ $s = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($webUrl)
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\C\Documents\SPListExtract.ps1:6 char:1
+ $w = $s.OpenWeb()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Users\C\Documents\SPListExtract.ps1:7 char:1
+ $l = $w.Lists[$library]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

so i edited that code a bit but i only get the item in the list and not the attachments that are in the items. The code that i wrote is as follows:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url 'https://mm.sharepoint.com/teams/pj-b0000' -UseWebLogin
$tempLocation = "C:\Users\C\Documents\temp"
$list = Get-PnPListItem -List 'Photos'

foreach ($listItem in $list)
{
    Write-Host "    Content: " $listItem.ID 
    $destinationfolder = $tempLocation + "\" + $listItem.ID          
    if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationfolder))        
    {            
        $dest = New-Item $destinationfolder -type directory          
    }
    foreach ($attachment in $listItem.Attachments)    
    {        
        $file = $w.GetFile($listItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix + $attachment)        
        $bytes = $file.OpenBinary()                
        $path = $destinationfolder + "\" + $attachment
        Write "Saving $path"
        $fs = new-object System.IO.FileStream($path, "OpenOrCreate") 
        $fs.Write($bytes, 0 , $bytes.Length)    
        $fs.Close()    
    }
}
```

I see my problem is the inside foreach loop for the $file variable I think. Would someone be able to help me with this?

Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first line in your errors implies you do not have the assembly loaded:

```
new-object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

These assemblies are only installed on a SharePoint server:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4a78ed2c-efde-40fa-800c-c4ecfa68a7c4/cannot-find-type-microsoftsharepointspsite-when-running-sharepoint-powerscript-in-a-windows-10?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: Thank you. Yes i did see that link before too, that's why i edited the code at the top. To my understanding the loop shouldn't be effected by it.

Comment: The native PowerShell cmdlet (Get-PnpListItem) may not return the exact same data format, or even the data that you require. Have you confirmed with a single query that the data you receive contains what you are looking for?